# How to get values of selected options in Form api?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using Form api to build one form.In that I have used select type field and for that options are coming from an array. Below is the code

```
  $fnames = array();
  $dir_path = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path(). '/files');
  $files1 = scandir($dir_path); 
  $dirs = glob($dir_path . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $directs){
     $names = explode('/', $directs);//
     $fnames[] = end($names);
    }

  $form['select_list'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Folder Names'),
    '#options' => $fnames,
  );
```

While displaying on the select list it will display all names but when I will fetch the value in one of the submit function it will show only index value not the name.

```
function custom_submit_file_upload($form, &$form_state){
  $foldername = $form_state['values']['select_list'];
}
```

Here it shows,

```
$foldername = 0 or 1 or 2 whatever I select in the options,
```

but I need name of the selected element not the index values.
Please suggest me to get the names.Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the form submission handler has access to the `$form` variable, you just use the following code.

```
$foldername = $form['select_list']['#options'][$form_state['values']['select_list']];
```

To make it clear with an example: `$form['select_list']['#options']` is an array like `array( 1 => 'first folder', 2 => 'second folder')`, and `$form_state['values']['select_list']` is a value between 1 and 2.